# How to disconnect mongodb (.net driver 2.0)

Tags: c#, mongodb

Old API, I can disconnect the mongodb server.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
.
.
.
client.GetServer().Disconnect();
```

but New API, the GetServer() Expired.
and async issue ... is need to disconnect mongodb server?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't disconnect from mongodb server, because connections are managed by connection pool.

> Creating new authenticated connections to the database is expensive. So, instead of creating and destroying connections for each request to the database, you want to re-use existing connections as much as possible. This is where connection pooling comes in.
>   http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/11/deep-dive-into-connection-pooling/

Comment: great answer, I don't understand why mongo don't mention this in the .net driver reference under connecting (currently http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/connecting/)